# Debugging a Route in Symfony2

Tags: routes, symfony

I am having trouble figuring out what is wrong with a singe *route* in my Symfony2 routing YML file.  Every other route is working just fine (and I have a couple dozen already), but this one route refuses to be recognized.

Here is the relevant clip of my YML file:

```
ProjectMainBundle_util_initUpload:
    pattern:  /util/initUpload
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectMainBundle:Utilities:initUpload }
    requirements:
        _method:  POST

ProjectMainBundle_util_init:
    pattern:  /util/init
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectMainBundle:Utilities:initUtilities }
    requirements:
        _method:  POST

ProjectMainBundle_util_download:
    pattern:  /util/download
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectMainBundle:Utilities:download }
    requirements:
        _method:  GET
```

The first route, '/util/initUpload', returns a '**No route found for "POST /util/initUpload"** error.  I've tried placing the block at different places (even moving it above '/util/init'.)  The '/' index route is at the end of my routing.yml document, so that shouldn't be the problem.  The routes above are the only ones in the format /util/*.

The route serves to handle a form and file upload, but I don't think that matters.  I've removed the POST requirement and tested it directly in the browser, and that still gave me the same error..  The camelCase shouldn't be a problem.  I have other routes in that format that work just fine...

What else am I missing?  Any suggestions on how to debug this?  My next step is to scrap the YML file and rewrite using the php format, though I really don't want to do that..

Answer (score 20):

There is a command to list all of your routes:

**For Symfony 2.x** -

```
app/console router:debug
```

**For Symfony 3.x and above** -

```
bin/console debug:router
```

If you don't see your route in there, first try clearing the cache. If it doesn't help, delete the route definition and retype it again manually — don't copy/paste.

P.S. It has nothing to do with YAML/PHP.

Comment: The use of "router:debug" command is deprecated since version 2.7 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the "debug:router" instead.